# Custom image in Graphical Indicators - Project Server 2016

Tags: project-server, project, graphical-indicators

I'm working on Project Server 2016.

I want to have custom image in the Graphical Indicators of Custom Field other than the ones provided by SharePoint.

Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the out-of-the-box way or possibilities, but you can just replace the PNG files on your front-end server. I know, it's a pretty dirty way, but it's working well.

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\INC\PWA\IMAGES\cf_{0-64}p.png
```